# Simplifying a Recursive Function

Tags: c, recursion

I have a recursive function that sums all even numbers within an integer range inclusively. The code I have right now works properly, but it looks like it can be simplified. I've tried putting the recursive function in different spots, but every time I get the wrong answer. Can you guys show me how I can shorten my code?

```
int sum_evens(int range_start, int range_end)
{
   int even_sum = 0; /* The inclusive sum of all even numbers within  */
                     /* whole number range                            */

   printf("\n   Entering sum function for range %d to %d", 
                                            range_start, range_end);
                                            
   if(range_start <= range_end)
   {
      if(is_even(range_start) == 0)
      {
         printf("\n      Adding: %d", range_start);
         even_sum = sum_evens(range_start + 1, range_end);
         even_sum += range_start;
      }
      else
      {
         printf("\n      Skipping: %d", range_start);
         even_sum = sum_evens(range_start + 1, range_end);
      } 
  }

  printf("\n   Exiting sum function for range %d to %d with result: %d",
     range_start, range_end, even_sum);
  
 return even_sum;

}
```

I'm basically trying to only have the line (even_sum  = sum_evens(range_start + 1, range_end);)

Comment: You can simplify it with math. Forget all about algorithms and recursive functions and loops, and find an arithmetic formula that will return the result directly.

Comment: A request for assistance with improving working code would be more appropriate for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do it iteratively. The code would definitely be simpler. I guess 4-5 lines of code, which is about half the number of lines of your code, not counting printfs. Abusing recursion is never a good idea

Comment: Sigh. Look, folks, essentially every question that asks for a recursive solution is a student exercise. Telling them to do it without recursion violates the terms of the exercise. When a physical education trainer tells a student athlete to lift weights on a weight machine multiple times, you do not tell them that is inefficient and they ought to get a forklift or level. They need to lift weights to train their muscles, and students need to exercise and train their brains by writing code that would be pointless outside of exercises.

Comment: isn't this a simple arithmetic progression? from 1-N, while skipping those less than `range_start` ? or to put it differently, sum of evens from 1 to N, and deducting the sum of evens from 1 to `range_start` ?

Comment: Typo: “level” → “lever” in my previous comment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True... but it's so sad to see all these student exercises that must use recursion to solve problems that should never be solved using recursion. Why can't teachers come up with homework task where recursion makes sense?

Comment: @EricPostpischil if recursion is required, they should write this explicitely in the question.

Comment: @4386427 that doesn't sound right either. Lets look at a simple case, sum evens from 4 to 10. 1) 1-10: `2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 = 30` 2) 1-4: `2 + 4 = 6`  3) 4-10: `4 + 6 + 8+ 10 = 18`, By using your formula `2 * sum(1,5) - 2 * sum(1,4)` right?  .... actually nvm, you're right, i spotted my typo :D

Comment: @Jabberwocky: You should know by now that any problem on this level that mentions recursion is a student exercise for which recursion is required.

Comment: @4386427: Why cannot physical education teachers come up with tasks where lifting weights makes sense? Instead of lifting weights and putting them back down, students should be made to do physical labor around the school. But that is not practical. There is not always that sort of labor available to be done, and it is irregular, whereas with the weight machines you have measured weights and counted repetitions. Students just learning these concepts need to be given simplified problems. It is the nature of training bodies and brains.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well... I have to disagree. In programming it makes no sense to teach a specific pattern using a problem where the pattern doesn't apply. IMO it causes more confusion than it helps.

Comment: @4386427: The sense it makes is that what is being taught is not when to use the pattern, any more than lifting weights teaches you when to lift weights on training machines in real life, but to teach the mechanisms by which the pattern works and to train the brain to understand it, the same way lifting weights trains muscles, by actual use and repetition.

Comment: @4386427:  Furthermore, the fundamental nature of recursion, with a function calling itself and maintaining multiple distinct contexts separately, is weird to some students and requires puzzling out and experimentation before it becomes second nature. That sort of learning needs to be done with simplified examples. Training students about recursion for the first time using complicated examples where it is justified would increase the difficulty unnecessarily.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I still disagree. The best way to teach a pattern is IMO using an example where the student can see the benefit of using it. Teach a pattern with an example not suitable for the pattern requires you to say "But never do like this"... Leaving the student more confused. Anyway - this is probably not the place for this discussion ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is a math formula for calculating this but if you really need recursion, you can try:

```
int sum_evens(int range_start, int range_end)
{
    if (range_start > range_end) return 0;
    int tmp = (is_even(range_start) == 0) ? range_start : 0;
    return tmp + sum_evens(range_start + 1, range_end);
}
```

But notice that such a recursive function is "dangerous". Calling it like `sum_evens(0, 2000000000)` is very likely to generate a stack overflow.

So if you don't want to use the math formula, a much better approach would be a simple loop.

```
int sum_evens(int range_start, int range_end) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (is_even(range_start) != 0) ++range_start; // Make range_start even
    while(range_start <= range_end) 
    {
        sum += range_start;
        range_start += 2;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

BTW:

Your function `is_even` apparently return 0 when the number is even. That's rather unusual as the value 0 typically means false. However, in the above I kept the same style.

Comment: `sum_evensX` on the return line? probably a typo?

Comment: @Shark Thanks... the name used while testing and by mistake I only changed once

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want to do this recursively, but just like what the comments says, if you're looking for a better and faster solution you could use a simple iteration or the actual arithmetic formula, that being said

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_evens(int range_start, int range_end) {
    printf("Entering sum function for range %d to %d\n",
           range_start, range_end);

    if (range_start > range_end) return 0;
    int val = range_start % 2 == 0 ? range_start : 0;
    return val + sum_evens(range_start + 1, range_end);
}

int main() {
    int val = sum_evens(1, 10);
    printf("\n%d", val);
    return 0;
}
```

here instead of using an if else statement to add values to the total sum, you can use the ternary operator, and then call the function again to initiate a recursion

**If you want to use a void function and pointers**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void sum_evens(int range_start, int range_end, int * initiator) {

    printf("Entering sum function for range %d to %d\n", range_start, range_end);

    if (range_start <= range_end) {
        int val = range_start % 2 == 0 ? range_start : 0;
        (*initiator) += val;
        sum_evens(range_start + 1, range_end, initiator);
    }
}

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    sum_evens(1, 3, &sum);
    printf("\n%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

**Using iteration (for loop)**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_evens(int range_start, int range_end) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = range_start; i <= range_end; i++) 
        if (i % 2 == 0) sum += i;
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int val = sum_evens(1, 10);
    printf("\n%d", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @4386427 edited thanks for the feedback ^_^ also i see you wrote the answer way before me lol, leaving an upvote

Comment: Well, 4 min is within the acceptable time for "identical" solutions to be posted so no worries.

Comment: Ty have a great one :D

Answer (score 0):

Nothing more to add but I have a habit of writing the base condition at first so as to decrease the execution time and the space it will allocate, as in here your function went up to n+1 also which is unnecessary.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).